# How to get two result rows from one table row

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MYSQL query:

```
<?php

require "gospel_connect.php";


if(isset($_GET["keywords"])) {
  $keywords = $db->escape_string($_GET["keywords"]);
  $query = $db->query("SELECT *,
  CASE
    WHEN scriptures LIKE '%{$keywords}%' THEN scriptures_link
    WHEN books LIKE '%{$keywords}%' THEN books_link
  END as the_link
FROM data WHERE scriptures LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR books LIKE '%{$keywords}%'");

  ?>

  <div class='result-count'>
    Found <?php echo $query->num_rows; ?> results.
  </div>
  <?php

  if($query->num_rows) {
    while($r = $query->fetch_object()) {
      ?>
        <div class='result'>
          <?php
            $link = $r->the_link;

          echo "<a href='$link'> Hi </a> <br>";
          ?>
        </div>
      <?php
    }
  }

}
```

Let me explain, the query is searching from the db table `data` and it has the following columns: `id`, `date`, `scriptures`, `books`, `scriptures_link`, `books_link`.

Now, the query is working perfectly. It returns the respective link. The problem is that if *both* `scriptures` and `books` match with keywords, only one result will show. I want both to appear if both have matches. Otherwise, I only want one set to return information. **How can I accomplish this?**

Comment: replace `OR` by `AND` ? seems pretty straightforward. as per *"I want both to appear if both have matches."*

Comment: @Fred -ii - It's now all messed up...

Comment: Define *"messed up"* ;-)

Comment: You should also consider switching from `MySQL` as it has been [officially](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) deprecated. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) **with** [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @Fred-ii- I can't really. The results returned seem to be slightly unlogical and make no sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want two rows returned from one row in the database table. In your case, you should then use `UNION ALL` to obtain the desired result:

```
SELECT *, scriptures_link AS the_link
FROM data WHERE scriptures LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
UNION ALL
SELECT *, books_link AS the_link
FROM data WHERE books LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
```

This query will also work (after changing table names), if you split your table into two, one for scriptures and one for books. This will probably be a better database design.  Another possibility is to use one row for each possible match, and then add a column (*e.g.* source) to identify the source of the data.